# How to combine data from many models with the same data structure into a view - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

We have an application that has a series of models in Rails that all have the same data structure. We'd like to now create a view that displays all the data from these models together, in the one table. The reason for the separation into many models is it all comes from different sources.

So as an administrator I would like to view all the data together.

This data is read only so there is no need to write.

With a controller, I can grab the information from each model into an array, like so:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @dingoat = Dingoat.all
    @dingobe = Dingobe.all  
  end
end
```

Now on my view, how do I 'combine' this information? I can show it separately, like so:

```
<% @dingoat.each do |dingoat| %>
  <li><%= dingoat.ProductName %></li>
<% end %>
<% @dingobe.each do |dingobe| %>
  <li><%= dingobe.ProductName %></li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you combine these into a single model and add :source attribute to differentiate the source. That being said, if you really want to work with them seperately you can combine the records in your controller like this:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @records = Dingoat.all + Dingobe.all
  end
end
```

Then the view simplifies to this:

```
<% @records.each do |record| %>
  <li><%= record.product_name %></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Awarding the answer to @infused as he replied the fastest

Comment: A long shot, but do you know this would be done in  ActiveAdmin?

Comment: No, but maybe something in the [custom action docs](http://activeadmin.info/docs/8-custom-actions.html) will help.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's not enough detail to diagnose fully I won't try to discuss whether splitting up this data into separate models is actually a good idea or not, but suffice it to say that it points to a likely design issue.
However, getting all the records into a common collection to output in a read-only fashion is quite easy:

```
def index
  @dings = Dingoat.all + Dongobe.all
end
```

Then in the view I would recommend calling a partial like this:

```
<% render partial: "ding", collection: @dings %>
```

Then the _ding.html.erb partial could be:

```
<li><%= ding.ProductName %></li>
```

Comment: A long shot, but do you know this would be done in ActiveAdmin?

Comment: I haven't used ActiveAdmin. However, I'd say that if you should only use it if you're in the sweet spot it. It looks to me like its sweet spot would be a straightforward admin UI for a model. If you want to go that route you'll want to combine your various models into one model and differentiate them some other way than separate models.